# jQuery - Trouble with an exercise of animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to make an animation. I have some boxes inside a div. The div is positioned relative and the children are positioned absolute.

What I'm trying to do with jQuery is to animate the boxes inside the div. The animation will consist that when the page charges, then each box will apear. By default the initial opacity is 0 on CSS.

And for that there are no problems, the main problem here is that I only want "rows" of 4 boxes, and then another row and so on. I have been thinking on how to do that, I just can do it for 2 rows (8 boxes) but when there are more than 8 I have problems.

Help! Thanks! :D

```
function boxAnimation(){
    $(".num").each(function(i){
        delay = i *500;
        offsetLeft = i * 120;
        offsetTop = i * 0;
        if(i >= 4){
            offsetLeft = (i-4) * 120;
            offsetTop = 120;
        }
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            left:offsetLeft+"px",
            top: offsetTop+"px"
            },
            200,
            function(){
            $(this).css("opacity","1");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or plunkr demonstrating this?

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer section below, that's much better than writung "solved" into the title.

Comment: Great! Include some explanation what was the problem and it would be perfect. :)

Comment: Brilliant. :) I think you will have to wait a period of time before you can mark your own answer as accepted. In all this is a pretty good start - have fun on the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had, was that each row of the animation have 4 boxes, so I had to calculate the `Offsetop` and also the `offsetLeft`, for that I used this operation:

1. `i%4` Which gives me the numeration from 0 to 3 (each row has now 4 boxes)
   and that `* 120` for the `OffsetLeft`
2. `1/4` Which gives me `0..1..2..` and so on, but with intervals of 4, this means that when I have 4 boxes, then the offset increments on 1, then plus 1,.. and so on. If you want all the row to have exact the same top you must add `Math.floor(i/4)`.

For example, suppose we have the box seven so `i = 7`. Then the box seven must have to go in the 2° row on the 4° column because 7 in programming is equal to the box 8 (numbering from 0 to 7) Knowing that we have:

"Column" Horizontal move Calculation -> i%4 * 120 -> 7%4 * 120 -> 3 * 120 -> **360**

For my exercise we have:
0 - 1 Column
120 - 2 Column
240 - 3 Column
**360 - 4 Column**

"Row" Vertical move Calculation -> i/4 * 120 -> 7/4*120 -> 1*120 -> **120**

0 - 1 Row
**120 - 2 Row**
240 - 3 Row
..

```
function boxAnimation(){
    $(".num").each(function(i){
        delay = i *300;
        offsetLeft = i%4 * 120;
        offsetTop = i/4 * 120;
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            left:offsetLeft+"px",
            top: offsetTop+"px"
            },
            400,
            function(){
            $(this).css("opacity","1");
        });
    });
}
```